# File uploading in express using multer

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to upload image using multer but getting error,uploads is not a function.Here is my code

```
var multer = require('multer');
var uploads = multer({dest: './images'});
app.post('/uploading', uploads.single('image'), function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.file);
var file = __dirname + '/' + req.file.filename;
  uploads(req.file.path, file, function(err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.send(500);
    } else {
      res.json({
        message: 'File uploaded successfully',
        filename: req.file.filename
      });
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var multer = require('multer');
var uploads = multer({dest: './images'});
app.post('/uploading', uploads.single('image'), function(req, res) {

 yourModel.create(req.body,function(err,result){
   console.log(result);
 });

});
```

Comment: file name is already showing but how can i upload image and save name to database ?

Comment: model means your collection name you can call directly your collection here db.yourcollectionname

Answer (score 0):

As @Kuldeep said you don't have to the `uploads(filePath, file, (err) => {...})` inside the route.

When you are using multer as middleware (the middle function) multer will automatically upload the file and expose the filename, originalName etc to `req.file` object inside the route

```
var multer = require('multer');
var uploads = multer({dest: './images'});
app.post('/uploading', uploads.single('image'), function(req, res) {
// here just write the success or error login

});
```

Reference You can check here: [here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/express-file-uploads-with-multer#toc-upload-single-file)

EDIT: The above code will upload the **file with hex string as filename without any extension.**

In order to add rename function you need to use `diskStorage`. Here is the code taken from [this github issue](https://github.com/expressjs/multer/issues/170#issuecomment-123362345) page.

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, './images/')
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    crypto.pseudoRandomBytes(16, function (err, raw) {
      cb(null, raw.toString('hex') + Date.now() + '.' + mime.extension(file.mimetype)); //this is the rename func
    });
  }
});
var uploads = multer({ storage: storage });
```

Now you can use the `uploads` variable as middleware as shown in the above snippet.

Comment: image not uploading, a file with any string name is storing

Comment: That's the image :) that's the default behaviour. Just add an extension and open it. I am adding the code for the rename function for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Its quite obvious; **uploads is not a function** but uplaod is. So use

```
upload.single('image')
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a great, soup-to-nuts guide on using Multer (the website is just a little lacking for newbies) so here's my stab at it.

After using:

```
npm install multer --save
```

to add it to your project.

For me, I wanted to capture files on a specific route, namely:

```
/customers/:id/upload
```

So, I went into my customers.js route file and added:

```
var multer = require('multer');
```

as well as the code to set up the storage (diskStorage) and filename configuration tweaks:

```
var storage=multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function(req,file,cb){
    cb(null,'/uploads/');
  },
  filename: function(req,file,cb){
    cb(null,file.fieldname+'-'+Date.now());
  }
});
```

I could then create the upload middleware object that lets me specify, per route, how I would like Multer to handle file uploads. On the route above, I only want to receive one file with a particular internal filename so my customers.js route file looks like this:

```
router.post('/:id/targets/upload', upload.single('connections'), function(req,res,next){
  console.log("Router:POST: Companies/:_id/upload");
  console.log(req.file);
  ...
});
```

All of the examples I saw had stuff being added to the app.js file but these seemed a bit awkward and contrived as examples. Every route may have different file handling needs so it just seemed more appropriate, to me, to configure Multer on a per-controller basis. YMMV.